# Ошибка CS0246 The type or namespace name 'StreamReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int a=0; //5
        int b=0; //4
        int c=0; //3
        int d=0; //2

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("mark.txt");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(ran.Next(2, 6));
        }
        sw.Close();
        StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader("mark.txt");
        while (a==0)
        {
            int y = int.Parse(sr1.ReadLine());
            if (y == 5)
                a++;
            if (y == 4)
                b++;
            if (y == 3)
                c++;
            if (y == 2)
                d++;
        }
                label1.Text = "Кол-во пятёрок =" + a;
        label2.Text = "Кол-во четвёрок =" + b;
        label3.Text = "Кол-во троек =" + c;
        label4.Text = "Кол-во двоек =" + d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавь пространство имен, и нет директории using StreamReader